# HTML5 Microdata format for location and temperature?

Tags: html, microdata

What would be the most semantic way to mark up a location and its temperature? I was thinking of HTML5 Microdata but didn't come across anything that would be appropriate.

For example:

**New York, NY 100°**

Answer (score 2):

There is a format for locations http://schema.org/Place, I don't think there is one for temperature, but you could say that weather is an event and use something like this.

```
<div itemprop="event" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
  <span itemprop="location">New York NY, US</span>
  <meta itemprop="startDate" content="2011-05-23">May 23
  <span itemprop="name">100&deg;</span>
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jBJkU/

more info here: http://schema.org/Event